# Continuous Axis Chart with Slider Range won't draw?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, google-visualization

I'm finding myself in over my head on this web development project, and was hoping someone could help me better understand why one of my google charts will not draw on my page.

I have a working test page with the chart drawing how I want it, this is the jsfiddle for it so you can have the exact code if you wish to test 
http://jsfiddle.net/dlaliberte/pfTqP/

I pulled the code directly from this page where it works, and put it into my page that already has 4 other working google charts on it. Now when I add in this chart it doesn't give me any errors but it just will not draw.

I'm going to post the javascript for the first chart that works and the chart I'm trying to fix **(separated with '###')**, and the spot on my page where it's set to draw, I'm hoping someone with more experience could help me spot where the issue is coming from, as after several hours of tweaking and running over it I'm still not sure what's going wrong.

```
    //################################### UPDATED JAVASCRIPT ####################################
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
         <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


         <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
         <script src="js/jquery.csv.min.js"></script>

             <script type="text/javascript"> // load the visualisation API

                google.charts.load('visualization', 'current', '1.1', 
                    {
                        callback: drawCharts,
                        packages: ['corechart', 'controls']
                    });


    /* Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawLineChart);
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBarChart);
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    */
    function drawCharts() {
        drawLineChart();
        drawBarChart();
        drawBarVisualization();
        drawPieVisualization();
        drawVisualization();
    }

    function drawLineChart() {
      var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "getData.php",
          dataType: "json",
          async: false
          }).responseText;

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
        var options = {
                        title: 'Average Ratings',
            'vAxis': { title: "Average Rating" },
            'width': 1100, 
            'height': 540,
            'legend': { position: 'bottom'},
            'is3D':true,
            'padding': 20,
            'backgroundColor': 'Ivory',
            'color':'Black',
            hAxis: {
                textStyle:{color: 'Black', weight: 'bold'}
                    },
            series: 
            {
            0: { color: 'Black', pointShape: 'square'},
            }


        }
      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

      chart.draw(data, options);


      google.visualization.events.addListener('testBtn', 'click',
      function(event) {
        data.sort({column: 0, desc: false});
        chart.draw(data, options);
      });

      changeLineRange = function() {
          data.sort({column: 0, desc: false});
          chart.draw(data, options);
        };

      changeLineRangeBack = function() {
          data.sort({column: 0, desc: true});
          chart.draw(data, options);
        };


    }


    function drawBarChart() {
      var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "getData.php",
          dataType: "json",
          async: false
          }).responseText;

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

        var options = {
            title: 'Average Ratings',
            'vAxis': { title: "Average Rating" },
            'width': 700, 
            'height': 540,
            'legend':{position:'top',alignment:'start'},
            'is3D':true,
            'padding': 20,
            'backgroundColor': 'Ivory',
            series: {
            0: { color: 'Black' },
          },
          'hAxis': {
                    title: "Date",
                    gridlines: { count: 3, color: '#CCC' },
                    format: 'dd-MMM-yyyy'
                }


        }
      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.

      var chart2 = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('bar_chart_div'));

      chart2.draw(data, options);


      changeOptions = function() {
          chart2.setOption('is3D', true);
          chart2.draw();
        };
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
});


$('#myTabs a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})



        //Triple Line Chart

            function drawVisualization() {
               $.get("MockWeek.csv", function(csvString) {
                  // transform the CSV string into a 2-dimensional array
                  var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar}, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});

                  // this new DataTable object holds all the data
                  var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);
                  // CAPACITY - En-route ATFM delay - YY - CHART
                  var crt_ertdlyYY = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
                     chartType: 'LineChart',
                     containerId: 'crt_ertdlyYY',
                     dataTable: data,
                     options:{
                         'title': 'Average Ratings',
                        'vAxis': { title: "Average Rating" },
                        'width': 1100, 
                        'height': 540,
                        'backgroundColor': 'Ivory',
                        'color':'Black',
                        'hAxis': {
                    title: "Date",
                    gridlines: { count: 3, color: '#CCC' },
                    format: 'dd-MMM-yyyy'
                },
                        title: 'KWh Usage - Temperature Projected',
                        titleTextStyle : {color: 'Black', fontSize: 14},
                        curveType: 'function'
                     }
                  });
                  crt_ertdlyYY.draw();




                  changeRange = function() {
          data.sort({column: 0, desc: false});
          crt_ertdlyYY.draw();
        };

            changeRangeBack = function() {
          data.sort({column: 0, desc: true});
          crt_ertdlyYY.draw();
        };
               });
            }
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization)




    //Triple Pie Chart

            function drawPieVisualization() {
               $.get("Thornton.M2.csv", function(csvString) {
                  // transform the CSV string into a 2-dimensional array
                  var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar}, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});


                  // this new DataTable object holds all the data
                  var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);
                  // CAPACITY - En-route ATFM delay - YY - CHART
                  var pieMain = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
                     chartType: 'BarChart',
                     containerId: 'pieMain',
                     dataTable: data,
                     options:{
                         title: 'Bar Chart Test',
                        'vAxis': { title: "Bar Chart Test" },
                        'width': 1100, 
                        'height': 530,
                        'backgroundColor': 'Ivory',
                        'color':'Black',
                        'hAxis': {
                    title: "Date",
                    gridlines: { count: 3, color: '#CCC' },
                    format: 'dd-MMM-yyyy'
                },
                        title: 'Bar Chart Test',
                        titleTextStyle : {color: 'Black', fontSize: 16},
                     }
                  });
                  pieMain.draw();
               });
            }
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawPieVisualization)

            changeRange = function() {
          pieMain.sort({column: 0, desc: false});
          pieMain.draw();
        };

            changeRangeBack = function() {
          pieMain.sort({column: 0, desc: true});
          pieMain.draw();
        };



function drawVisualization() {
  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
       document.getElementById('dashboard'));

   var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
     'controlType': 'ChartRangeFilter',
     'containerId': 'control',
     'options': {
       // Filter by the date axis.
       'filterColumnIndex': 0,
       'ui': {
         'chartType': 'LineChart',
         'chartOptions': {
           'chartArea': {'width': '90%'},
             'hAxis': {'baselineColor': 'none' }
         },
         // Display a single series that shows the closing value of the stock.
         // Thus, this view has two columns: the date (axis) and the stock value (line series).
         'chartView': {
           'columns': [0, 3]
         },
         // 1 day in milliseconds = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 = 86,400,000
         'minRangeSize': 86400000
       }
     },
     // Initial range: 2012-02-09 to 2012-03-20.
     'state': {'range': {'start': new Date(2012, 1, 9), 'end': new Date(2012, 2, 20)}}
   });

   var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
     'chartType': 'CandlestickChart',
     'containerId': 'chart',
     'options': {
       // Use the same chart area width as the control for axis alignment.
       'chartArea': {'height': '80%', 'width': '90%'},
       'hAxis': {'slantedText': false},
       'vAxis': {'viewWindow': {'min': 0, 'max': 2000}},
       'legend': {'position': 'none'}
     },
     // Convert the first column from 'date' to 'string'.
     'view': {
       'columns': [
         {
           'calc': function(dataTable, rowIndex) {
             return dataTable.getFormattedValue(rowIndex, 0);
           },
           'type': 'string'
         }, 1, 2, 3, 4]
     }
   });

   var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
   data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
   data.addColumn('number', 'Stock low');
   data.addColumn('number', 'Stock open');
   data.addColumn('number', 'Stock close');
   data.addColumn('number', 'Stock high');


   // Create random stock values, just like it works in reality.
   var open, close = 300;
   var low, high;
   for (var day = 1; day < 121; ++day) {
     var change = (Math.sin(day / 2.5 + Math.PI) + Math.sin(day / 3) - Math.cos(day * 0.7)) * 150;
     change = change >= 0 ? change + 10 : change - 10;
     open = close;
     close = Math.max(50, open + change);
     low = Math.min(open, close) - (Math.cos(day * 1.7) + 1) * 15;
     low = Math.max(0, low);
     high = Math.max(open, close) + (Math.cos(day * 1.3) + 1) * 15;
     var date = new Date(2012, 0 ,day);
     data.addRow([date, Math.round(low), Math.round(open), Math.round(close), Math.round(high)]);
   }




   dashboard.bind(control, chart);
   dashboard.draw(data);
}


    </script>
```

And here is the spot I'm drawing the chart on my page, it's in a set of 4 tabs so the user can tab through different charts, so far it's worked perfectly.

```
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h2 align="center" class="featurette-heading">Current Demand -<span style="color: Ivory;"> Hourly Usage</span></h2>
          <br/>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" data-tabs="tabs">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" class="buttonAnimate" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Usage</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" class="buttonAnimate"  aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Demand</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" class="buttonAnimate"  aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Daily</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" class="buttonAnimate"  aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Monthly</a></li>

  </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" align="center" id="home"> <div class="chart" id="chart_div"></div> 
      <button class="btn btn-primary raised" onclick="changeLineRange();">
                Ascending
              </button>

              <button class="btn btn-primary raised" onclick="changeLineRangeBack();">
                Descending
              </button><br /></div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" align="center" id="profile"><div  class="chart" id="crt_ertdlyYY"></div>

      <button class="btn btn-primary raised" onclick="changeRange();">
                Ascending
              </button>

              <button class="btn btn-primary raised" onclick="changeRangeBack();">
                Descending
              </button><br /></div>


  // ############################## THIS IS THE TAB PANEL WHERE I'M DRAWING THE NEW CHART ############################

      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade">
        <div  class="chart" id="dashboard">
            <div id="chart" style='width: 915px; height: 300px;'></div>
            <div id="control" style='width: 915px; height: 50px;'></div>
        </div>
    </div>

      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="settings"><div  class="chart" id="pieMain"></div></div>
    </div>



        </div>
```

I'm not sure what else you might need to see, again I'm out of my element here and trying to get a grasp on how to achieve this, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a couple issues here...

first, code is mixed from both the old and new versions of google charts

the old library uses `jsapi` to load the library

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

the new library uses the `gstatic` library

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new `gstatic` loader from now on.

next, the `load` statement and `callback` should only be used once per page

once the `callback` fires, you can draw as many charts as needed

the `callback` can also be placed directly in the `load` statement

try setup similar to the following...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawCharts,
  packages: ['controls', 'corechart']
});

function drawCharts() {
  drawLineChart();
  drawVisualization();
}

function drawLineChart() {
  ...
}

function drawVisualization() {
  ...
}
```